# pythonにおけるヒストグラムの作成について

Tags: python

pythonにおいて複数のcsvデータをヒストグラムにしたいと考えております。
以下のスクリプトは１つのcsvファイルのデータをヒストグラムにする為のものになります。

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("default_list_1.csv")

df = df['detime']
df.hist()

# タイトル追加
plt.title('detime_count')

# x軸にscore、y軸にfreq
plt.xlabel('detime')
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.show()
```

このヒストグラムに複数のcsvファイルのデータを積み重ねていくにはどのようにスクリプトを変更したらよいでしょうか。
尚、default_list_〇.csvはdefault_list_1.csv～default_list_1000.csvまであります。
このデータを全て一つのヒストグラムで表したいと考えております。

初歩的な内容で申し訳ございませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 実際の質問内容としては「複数のファイルからデータを読み込むには？」ではありませんか？恐らくヒストグラムの作成部分はできているのですよね？ / 質問文はあとからでも [編集] できるので、質問内容に沿ったタイトルを付けておくと回答を得られる機会も増えるかと思います。

Comment: @Daaaaai39 さん、もしかするとアカウントがふたつに分かれてしまっているかもしれません。質問者ご本人のアカウントであれば編集や回答の承認などが自由にできます。ヘルプセンターの[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できないかお試しくださいませ。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/218731

Comment: teratail.comは外部サイトであり、stackoverflowとは無関係です。外部サイトと質問が重複することを根拠に質問を制限すべきだとは思いません。stackoverflowのルールとしてそのような重複排除のルールがあるのでしょうか。

Comment: @sugiyamath さん、制限・排除ではなく気を付けて下さい、というものです。この辺を参考に [...マルチポストの扱い](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1766/26370), [...マルチポストについて](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2246/26370), [マルチポストとは...？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/26370), [...指摘するときのコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087/26370)。 ちなみに[**teratailでも推奨されていません**](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice) し、同様の議論もあります。[マルチポストの使い方がわかりません。](https://teratail.com/questions/56963)

Comment: @sugiyamath 回答される方に、他のサイトで既に回答済みでないか、見てみてくださいねという程度のコメントで、排除しようというものではありません。質問者さんに対して何も求めていません。また、インターネット上の同様のコンテンツにリンクを張っても原則として何も悪いことは無いと考えます。

Comment: htbさんのコメントに、回答者への警告のような印象を受けました。回答をつけるとき少しためらいました。「他のサイトで既に回答済みでないか、見てみてくださいね」のような簡単な説明があればよかったと思います。

Answer (score 2):

データファイル毎に柱を立てたい場合のコード例です。
※1000個も並べたら何が何だかわからなくなりそうです。

【コード例】

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv("S:\\work\\w041_python\\default_list_1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("S:\\work\\w041_python\\default_list_2.csv")

df1 = df1['detime']
df2 = df2['detime']
#df.hist()

labels = ['list_1', 'list_2']
plt.hist([df1,df2], label=labels)
plt.legend()
# タイトル追加
plt.title('detime_count')

# x軸にscore、y軸にfreq
plt.xlabel('detime')
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.show()
```

- コードの例は`default_list_1.csv`と`default_list_2.csv`の例です。
- read_csvに渡しているファイルのパス名は適当に読み替えてください。

【default_list_1.csv】

```
detime
1
2
3
3
```

【default_list_2.csv】

```
detime
1
2
2
1
2
```

【出力結果】
[image: 出力結果]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv("default_list_{}.csv".format(i+1)) for i in range(1000)])
df = df['detime']
df.hist()
plt.title('detime_count')
plt.xlabel('detime')
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.show()
```